# How to add to every value some other value in foreach loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, foreach

I have an array of doubles:

```
double[] arrayOfDoubles = new double[]{doubleVal1, doubleVal2, doubleVal3, doubleVal4, doubleVal5, doubleVal6};
```

and doubleValues initialization:

```
double doubleVal1 = 0;
double doubleVal2 = 0;
double doubleVal3 = 0;
double doubleVal4 = 0;
double doubleVal5 = 0;
double doubleVal6 = 0;
```

and now im using foreach loop with that array:

```
for (double val : arrayOfDoubles)
{
    val += 0.1;
}
```

i thinked it should add to every value(doubleVal1, doubleVal2..., doubleVal6) value 0.1.

What should i change to get that?

Comment: You're increasing the number, but not updating the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that with the advanced for loop, since `val` contains a copy of a value taken from the array, so modifying it doesn't modify the array.

Use a regular for loop instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i <  arrayOfDoubles.length; i++)
{
    arrayOfDoubles[i] += 0.1;
}
```

Comment: its just not possible using foreach loop?

Comment: Awesome, i didn't know val conatins a copy of a value.
Thanks.

Comment: @MadMike6661 Not unless you create a counter variable, increment it within the loop, and use it to update arrayOfDoubles[i] instead of val. You might as well use a normal for loop.

Comment: It is true. You can literally see that there is a new 'double val' created for each loop-increment.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular `for` loop, not a foreach, so that you can access the indexes of the array .

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<arrayOfDoubles.length; i++)
{
    arrayOfDoubles[i] += 0.1;
}
```

Also have a look at : [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: I've hesitate to mark it as a duplicate but seeing it here would be enough

Answer (score 2):

You can use foreach like this instead :

```
int i = 0;
for (double val : arrayOfDoubles) {
    arrayOfDoubles[i] += 0.1;
    i++;
}
```

Because for each in reality create a temp variable and not use the real values of array, it work like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfDoubles.length; i++) {
    double val = arrayOfDoubles[i];
    //      ^^---------------------------------for each create a temp variable like this
}
```

Comment: Really nice answer using the equivalent code! Note that this would not be the problem with non-primitive object (unless create new instance or immutable instance) ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should change your loop from the enhanced `for` loop to regular `for` loop, because loop variable modifications do not reflect on the original item:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != arrayOfDoubles.length ; i++) {
    arrayOfDoubles[i] += 0.1;
}
```

Note that this change would still have no effect on the fields `doubleVal1`..`doubleVal6`, which are *copied* into `arrayOfDoubles` on initialization. You cannot modify these without either referencing them directly, or using reflection (definitely not recommended for this task).

If your ultimate goal is to modify fields `doubleVal1`..`doubleVal6`, consider restructuring your class in a way that places these fields into an array permanently.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the point is to change the variables values, not the array's values. But this is not possible with primitives.

You can create a simple class holding the value, but I'm sure there is a better design approach for your task:

```
class DoubleHolder {
    double val;
}

DoubleHolder doubleVal1 = new DoubleHolder();
DoubleHolder doubleVal2 = new DoubleHolder();
DoubleHolder doubleVal3 = new DoubleHolder();
DoubleHolder doubleVal4 = new DoubleHolder();
DoubleHolder doubleVal5 = new DoubleHolder();
DoubleHolder doubleVal6 = new DoubleHolder();

DoubleHolder[] arrayOfDoubles = {doubleVal1, doubleVal2, doubleVal3, doubleVal4, doubleVal5, doubleVal6};

for (DoubleHolder dh : arrayOfDoubles) {
    dh.val += 0.1;
}

System.out.print(doubleVal3.val);      // prints 0.1
```